# Button won't link to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, button

```
<div class ="form-group">
    <div class ="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
             <input type = "button" value="Play Game" class="btn btn-primary" id="play">
         </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
play=document.getElementById("btn-primary");`
play.addEventListener("click", handleAdd, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

The id is 'play', not 'btn-primary'

Comment: i have tried this but the button is still not working.

Comment: The rest of the code is missing.  For example you'll also need a function handleAdd() {alert(1)} for example, for the callback.  Otherwise, you might want to post a full example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @SophieHudsonHamm also be sure you exectute the javascript *after* the html is defined.  Otherwise, the page is read from top to bottom in real time.  If the js executes first, the html doesn't exist yet (it's still downloading).